# Creating a javascript validation error

Tags: javascript, html, quickbase

I've got 3 fields that are used to enter 6 digits code for purpose of a database (Quickbase) query.  Each field needs an individual alert/msg  letting the submitter know if a code is invalid. Example:"The data entered in field #1 is invalid" . I put together the snippet below which somewhat achieves the results. Problem is when I enter just 1 field of bad data the script works but when I enter more than 1 field of bad data or mix good data with bad data the script does nto work properly... Thank you for your assitance.

Here are the fields

```
<input name="searchRecord" id="searchRecord1" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8" >
<input name="searchRecord" id="searchRecord2" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8">
<input name="searchRecord" id="searchRecord3" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8">
<input name="searchRecord" id="searchRecord4" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8"> 
<input name="searchRecord" id="searchRecord5" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8"> 
<input name="searchRecord" id="searchRecord6" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8">'
```

Here is the snippet

```
var js = req.responseText;
eval(js);

if (qdb_numrows == 0); {
    var x = true;
    var msg = "Precert 1:\n";
    if (document.getElementById('searchRecord1').value == qdb_numrows == 0) {
        if (qdb_numrows == 0) //only receive focus if its the first error
        document.getElementById('searchRecord1').focus();
        //change border to red on error (i would use a class change here...
        document.getElementById('searchRecord1').style.border = "solid 1px red";
        alert(msg = "Error: Data entered for field #1 not required for procedure code Or procedure code is not valid!\n");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('searchRecord2').value == qdb_numrows == 0) {
        if (qdb_numrows == 0) document.getElementById('searchRecord2').focus();
        document.getElementById('searchRecord2').style.border = "solid 1px red";
        alert(msg += "Error: Data entered for field #2 not required for procedure code Or procedure code is not valid!\n");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('searchRecord3').value == qdb_numrows == 0) {
        if (qdb_numrows == 0) //only receive focus if its the first error
        document.getElementById('searchRecord3').focus();
        //change border to red on error (i would use a class change here...
        document.getElementById('searchRecord3').style.border = "solid 1px red";
        alert(msg = "Error: Data entered for field #3 not required for procedure code Or procedure code is not valid!\n");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('searchRecord4').value == qdb_numrows == 0) {
        if (qdb_numrows == 0) //only receive focus if its the first error
        document.getElementById('searchRecord4').focus();
        //change border to red on error (i would use a class change here...
        document.getElementById('searchRecord4').style.border = "solid 1px red";
        alert(msg = "Error: Data entered for field #4 not required for procedure code Or procedure code is not valid!\n");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('searchRecord5').value == qdb_numrows == 0) {
        if (qdb_numrows == 0) //only receive focus if its the first error
        document.getElementById('searchRecord5').focus();
        //change border to red on error (i would use a class change here...
        document.getElementById('searchRecord5').style.border = "solid 1px red";
        alert(msg = "Error: Data entered for field #5 not required for procedure code Or procedure code is not valid!\n");
        valid = false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('searchRecord6').value == qdb_numrows == 0) {
        if (qdb_numrows == 0) //only receive focus if its the first error
        document.getElementById('searchRecord6').focus();
        //change border to red on error (i would use a class change here...
        document.getElementById('searchRecord6').style.border = "solid 1px red";
        alert(msg = "Error: Data entered for field #6 not required for procedure code Or procedure code is not valid!\n");
        valid = false;
    }

    //if (!qdb_numrows==0) alert(msg);
    //return false;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated. Do you have to use `eval`? eval is evil.

Comment: I don't think this does what you think it does: `x == y == z`

Comment: In addition to @tjameson, you in one place say `msg += ...` and in all other places do `msg = ...`, you probably want to append.

Comment: No I don't use eval.    I do think the error is in these lines ' if (document.getElementById('searchRecord6').value == qdb_numrows == 0)'  I'm basically trying to tell it that if the value of in this case searchRecord6 is not in the db then post he alert

Comment: Holy hell man, why not use a validation library or at least write a reusable function?

Comment: @user1839308 your code snippet *is* using `eval`.   And there is no triple equality check.  Your evaluation will be akin to taking the result of `documnet.getElementById('searchRecord6').value == qbd_numrows` which is either `true` or `false`  and then taking that value and comparing it against 0.  So therefore your `if` statement will evaluate to true iff `documnet.getElementById('searchRecord6').value != qbd_numrows`, since `false == 0` is `true` in javascript thanks to loose typing.

Comment: Side note, use [triple equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use) to avoid loose typing

Comment: Another issue, you have a semi-colon after your first `if` statement.  Therefore all the code in your block will always get run, regardless if `qdb_numrows` is 0 or not.